# 5000 twitter followers python

Tags: python, twitter, export

I have this code:

```
from twitter import *
twitter = Twitter(auth=OAuth(token, token_key, con_secret, con_secret_key))
username = "xxxxxxxxx"
query = twitter.followers.ids(screen_name = username)

print "found %d followers" % (len(query["ids"]))

for n in range(0, len(query["ids"]), 100):
     ids = query["ids"][n:n+100]

     subquery = twitter.users.lookup(user_id = ids)

     for user in subquery:
          # now print out user info, starring any users that are Verified.
          verified = " "
          if user["verified"]:
               verified = "*"
          print " [%s] %s" % (verified, user["screen_name"])
```

But only found 5000 followers and i have pretty much, how i can get all followers?

im using python 2.7.6 and the twitter module (easy_install twitter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids), results are given in groups of 5,000 user and you can get next ids using the `next_cursor` value given in the response.